# Update a cell in sql table with multiple scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a cell with value `cell = '0,B,1,D,4,T...'` (worst case)

What I want is updating the value to be `'b,B,d,D,t,T...'` (best case)

Sometimes I find the value can be `'0,B,d,D,t,T..'` so its value is not fixed.

What I want to do is do a sort of multiple checking in the cell and replace the bits that I want until it has the best case value. e.g :

```
UPDATE some_table
SET    some_table.some_col = REPLACE(some_table.some_col, '0,B', 'b,B')
WHERE  some_table.some_row = 'RELATED_ROW'
       AND some_table.some_col LIKE'%0,B%'

UPDATE some_table
SET    some_table.some_col = REPLACE(some_table.some_col, '1,D', 'd,D')
WHERE  some_table.some_row = 'RELATED_ROW'
       AND some_table.some_col LIKE'%1,D%'
.
.
.
```

But I want know if it's possible to do it in a single statement? so that I don't have to execute lots of separated `UPDATE` scripts.

Comment: Means, you need to update the all the numeric value with an alphabet (proceeding letter in lower case) right?

Comment: Why are you storing comma delimited values in the first place? That sounds like a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the multiple REPLACE calls into one another in a single statement:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET    some_table.some_col = REPLACE(REPLACE(...(some_table.some_col,
                               '0,B', 'b,B'),
                               '1,D', 'd,D'),
                               ...  , ...
                             )
WHERE  some_table.some_row = 'RELATED_ROW'
       AND (some_table.some_col LIKE '%0,B%'
         OR some_table.some_col LIKE '%1,D%'
         OR some_table.some_col LIKE ...
       )
;
```

Or, if this is SQL Server 2005+, you could go like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET    t.some_col = xN.result
FROM   some_table t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(t.some_col, '0,B', 'b,B')) x1 (result)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(x1.result , '1,D', 'd,D')) x2 (result)
       ...
       CROSS APPLY (...                                     ) xN (result)
WHERE  t.some_row = 'RELATED_ROW'
       AND (t.some_col LIKE '%0,B%'
         OR t.some_col LIKE '%1,D%'
         OR t.some_col LIKE ...
       )
;
```

In either case, you might also consider omitting the final part of the condition,

```
       AND (t.some_col LIKE '%0,B%'
         OR t.some_col LIKE '%1,D%'
         OR t.some_col LIKE ...
       )
```

if the impact of multiple `LIKE` tests overrides that of potential non-updating updates (i.e. updates that don't really change the value but, nevertheless, take place and, therefore, affect the overall performance).